# I want to set a footer with menu and I want to set icons equally divided as per the screen

Tags: android, android-menu

This is my .xml file and I just want to set all image view in horizontally in 
every screen... I tried but it's not happening.. help me for this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.example.sachin.attendence.MainActivity">
```

firstly i set relative layout
and all imageview as a menu

```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageViewFooter2"
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
       android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageViewFooter3"
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@drawable/att"
       android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageViewFooter4"
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
       android:background="@drawable/omlogo"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
    <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="01dp"
       android:background="#cec5ce"
       android:layout_above="@id/imageViewFooter3"
       android:id="@+id/view">

    </View>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

this was my .xml file

Comment: Weights only work in **LinearLayouts**. Or you can use **PercentRelativeLayouts**, instead (these ones are RelativeLayouts, but can use percentages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to reuse your footer in other screens. in that case you really should create different XML file just for the footer, and include it.

the following example `footer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#bbb" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />  <!-- your image here -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

I created simple drawable `icon` which i'm using in this example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <size
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="48dp" />
    <solid android:color="#757" /> <!-- your background-->
</shape>
```

To include your `footer.xml` file in any screen, use `include` tag like so:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```